Left Gutter is Annoyingly Wide in new 2024 IntelliJ IDEA

The left gutter is too wide. There doesn't seem to be any settings to change the gutter size. I've tried searching how to fix it online, official website, and on forums, but found nothing. Does anyone know how to fix this or do I simply need to wait for a fix?

Found the solution. I had distraction-free mode on. If you have the same problem, go to settings --> advanced settings --> Left margin in distraction-free mode and set it to 0 pixels.
